# Register and Unregister plugins using code - Spigot 1.16

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I'm trying to make an alias plugin that basically has a reload command that unregisters all the aliases, and registers the new aliases. I have a working code, but its a bit buggy. Like if I create new aliases then reload, the tab doesn't autocomplete but the new commands still work. And if I delete old commands then reload the commands still autocomplete and they still work even though I removed them from config.yml.
Here is my code currently:
https://github.com/codergautam/FastAliases/tree/37a0ba95c708776232315212b9e584df278a4f94

The code that reloads the command is in ReloadCommand.java in commands folder
The code that unregisters all commands is in UnregisterAll.java in alias folder
The code that loads the config/registers commands is in Configloader.java in the alias folder

Is there a way to fix this? and what am i doing wrong

thanks

Comment: You likely won't get an answer as your question reads: 'please fix my code in this repo'. Have a read of [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers). Ask a question that can be answered without having to compile your code.

Comment: alright, i will

Comment: i already got answersin my spigot thread

Comment: If you already have an Answer. Please mark this question as solved by writing an answer and accepting that answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use the `PlayerCommandSendEvent` to remove suggestions when it was sent to the player.